# GlassFish's JAXB implementation

Tags: jaxb, glassfish

I have faced with a problem while trying to deploy my web application to GlassFish 3.1.2. Looks like there is JAXB libraries conflict: my app uses v.1 JAXB implementation, while, AFAIK, GlassFish 3.1.2 contains its own v2 JAXB implementation. Can this overlap cause fail during deployment? How to act in this situation?

Exception message:

> Caused by: rpt.engine.util.EngineException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: theInstance]
>    - with linked exception:
>   [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: theInstance]]
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:160)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:308)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:313)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with the JAXB version bundled with Glassfish 3.1.2 which is 2.2.5.
 You can try to upgrade the bundled JAXB version manually:

- Download new version at http://jaxb.java.net/ (complete package)
- Backup the files **/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib/jaxb-osgi.jar** and **/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar**
- Extract the files **jaxb-osgi.jar** and **jaxb-api-osgi.jar** from **new-version.zip/lib** to **/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib/** and **/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib/endorsed/**